# Does a beer with one malt and one hop PLUS adjuncts count as a SMASH?

Tags: recipe, smash

Not sure if this is the right forum for this question..

A **SMASH** beer is **S**ingle **M**alt **A**nd **S**ingle Hop, and (from the recipes I've seen) *just* those - if you mashed with an adjunct like wheat would you still consider that a **SMASH** so long as there was only one malt in the grain bill?

Comment: I'd argue that what you propose adheres to the *letter* of the "law", but not so much the *spirit*. A compelling defense is definitely built in (i.e. that the adjunct is not malted), but I'm pretty sure most people would tend to expect something with a single grain, and not just a single (literal) malt. But, as Bureaucrat 1.0 said, *'you are technically correct... the best kind of correct'*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as you said "A SMASH beer is Single Malt And Single Hop".  And wheat malt is still a malt.  So yes, you can call it a SMASH beer.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect a SMASH beer to have 1 fermentable and 1 hop. I would consider base malt(barley, wheat or rye) + adjunct(any thing not the base malt but fermentable) + hop to be against the ethos of a SMASH beer.

It would then be a SMSAASH beer **S**ingle **m**alt, **s**ingle **a**djunct **a**nd **s**ingle **h**op.

You may have just invented a whole new category of craft beers!!